# Definitions of PKCS#11 abbreviations

Tags: pkcs11

Is there a complete definition list for all `CKx` abbreviations in PKCS#11? I believe I gathered most of them:

```
CK  = ... Data type or general constant
CKA = ... Attribute
CKC = ... Certificate type
CKD = ... Key derivation function
CKF = ... Bit flag
CKG = ... Mask generation function
CKH = ... Hardware features type
CKK = ... Key type
CKM = ... Mechanism type
CKN = ... Notification
CKO = ... Object class
CKP = ... Pseudo-random function
CKR = ... Return value
CKS = ... Session state
CKU = ... User type
CKZ = ... Salt/Encoding parameter
```

Are these correct? Am I missing any?

Comment: Wouldn't this be in the spec or library?

Comment: Note: there's a slight typo above (that I can't edit, since it's below the 6-character minimum!): `CKP` is the Pseudo-random function abbreviation, *not* `CKR`. `CKR` is only for return values.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They are defined in the standard, maintained on the [OASIS website](https://www.oasis-open.org)...[symbols and abbreviations](http://docs.oasis-open.org/pkcs11/pkcs11-base/v2.40/cs01/pkcs11-base-v2.40-cs01.html#_Toc399255260).

And the list there matches yours.